# Getting error java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade

Tags: jsf-2

I am getting error

> java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade

How can i resolve this error? I am using managedBeans in viewScope. Also creating a session using filter. What causing this exception happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have referenced a `HttpSession` as a property of some JSF managed bean class. This is an extremely bad design. Remove it and change your approach to just get it from the `FacesContext` in the thread local scope. But after all, this is still a smell, in properly designed JSF managed bean classes you should have **not** have any single line of `import javax.servlet...`. How to fix this properly depends on the concrete functional requirement which is not clear from your question at all. My first guess would be that you actually need a session scoped managed bean which is in turn injected by `@ManagedProperty`.